# Autohotkey: Activate hidden apps

Tags: windows, performance, autohotkey

I want to hide similar Apps from the taskbar, but want be able to bring them with AHK in the foreground. There are several Tweaks to hide Apps from the taskbar, but if I activate hiding, I can no more bring these Apps with AHK to foreground. Any help?

Comment: Would you mind adding your code? Sometimes it's hard to diagnose problems without seeing the issue and trying to duplicate it.

Answer (score 2):

You can show and bring to foreground hidden Apps by using the commands [WinShow](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinShow.htm) and [WinActivate](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinActivate.htm).

Example:

```
WinShow, ahk_class Notepad
WinActivate, ahk_class Notepad
```